# Switch primary monitor and audio device via shortcut

Tags: windows-10, audio, display, multiple-monitors, batch-file

Is there a way to fast switch the primary monitor and audio device in windows 10? I often switch between PC-monitor and speakers to connected TV (monitor and build in speakers). Manually switching these in windows all the time is clumsy.

Is there some shortcut or profile based solution, hopefully without installing additional software? Is this possible via a batch file or something?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [How to Change Default Audio Device in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/change-default-audio-device-windows-10/)

And to this
[Windows 10 Rundll32 Commands – the complete list](https://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-rundll32-command-list/)

---

Copy and paste this line on your Notepad or Notepad++ and save it as `SwitchSound.vbs` on your Desktop

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,0"
```

---

Or with a batch file like this : `SwitchSound.bat`

```
@echo off
Start rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,0
```

---

***Edit : 09/09/2020 @ 02:50*** :

I have bundled the complete list commands of `Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll` into an HTA file

[image]

---

And your command looks like here in 40 :

[image]

---

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
 APPLICATIONNAME="Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll Commands List by Hackoo 2020" 
 BORDER="THIN"
 BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
 ICON="DxDiag.exe"
 INNERBORDER="NO"
 MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
 MINIMIZEBUTTON="YES"
 SCROLL="NO"
 SELECTION="NO"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<head>
<title>Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll Commands List by Hackoo 2020</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color:lightblue;
    background-image: url('https://animaloilmaker.com/images/gif-green-matrix.gif');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<hr><br>
<select name="Command"></select>
<br><br><hr><br>
<Input Type="button" Value="Execute Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll Command" OnClick="Execute(Command.value)">
</center>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim URL,Save2File
URL = "https://pastebin.com/raw/F4AC0YDS"
Save2File = "Rundll32_Commands.csv"
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Window_OnLoad()
    CenterWindow 570,230
    Call Download(URL,Save2File)
    Call LoadFile(Save2File)
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    iTop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo iLeft, iTop
 End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub LoadFile(strFile)
Dim strContents,Count,Tab,i,objOption
    Call ClearListbox()
    strContents = ReadFile(strFile)
    Count = 0
    Tab = split(strContents,vbcrlf)
    For i = lbound(Tab) to ubound(Tab) Step 1
        Count = Count + 1
        Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
        objOption.Text =  Count & "-" & Trim(Split(Tab(i),";")(0)) 
        If i > UBound(tab) Then Exit For
        objOption.Value = Trim(Split(Tab(i),";")(1))
        Command.Add(objOption)      
    Next    
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ClearListbox()
Dim objOption
    For Each objOption in Command.Options
        objOption.RemoveNode
    Next 
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Execute(Command)
    Dim Title : Title = "Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll Commands List by Hackoo 2020"
    Dim Question
    Question = MsgBox("Did you want to execute this command ?" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
    Command,vbQuestion+VbYesNo,Title)
    If Question = vbYes Then
        CreateObject("wscript.Shell").Run Command,1,True
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Download(URL,Save2File)
    Dim File,Line,BS,ws
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    File.Open "GET",URL, False
    File.Send()
    If err.number <> 0 then
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error Getting File"
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " &  vbcrlf &_
        err.description
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source
        MsgBox Line,vbCritical,"Error getting file"
        Err.clear
        Self.close
    End If
    If File.Status = 200 Then ' File exists and it is ready to be downloaded
        Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
        BS.type = 1
        BS.open
        BS.Write File.ResponseBody
        BS.SaveToFile Save2File, 2
    ElseIf File.Status = 404 Then
        MsgBox "File Not found : " & File.Status,vbCritical,"Error File Not Found"
        Self.close
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Error : " & File.Status,vbCritical,"Error getting file"
        Self.close
    End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function ReadFile(InPutFile)
    Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InPutFile)
    sText = oTS.ReadAll
    oTS.close
    set oTS = nothing
    Set objFSO = nothing
    ReadFile = sText
End Function 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
```